# How do I get a bot to mention a channel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am making a welcome message but I can’t seem to make it say the rule channel. I want the bot to say #rules and make it so you can click it to go to the rules channel. I know you can do this with a normal user, but I want to do it with my bot. Every time I try, it can’t be clicked like a normal player. I’ve tried doing #rules, <#channelID>, and other stuff. None of them are clickable.

Comment: I know it is possible, as I have seen other bots do it.

Comment: Paste String with your welcome message

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to send a [`GuildChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/GuildChannel) for the channel name to be clickable.
You can achieve this by finding the channel in `guild.channels.cache`
This returns a Collection, which you can filter.
If you have an ID (easier):

```
var message = "Make sure to check the rules at " + 
  message.guild.channels.cache.get('channelID').toString();
```

If you want find the channel by ID (might break if you have multiple channels with the same name):

```
var message = "Make sure to check the rules at " + 
  message.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "rules").toString();
```

---

### EDIT:

Much easier way: in Discord mention the channel and put a `\` (backslash) before the channel name `\#rules`. You'll get something like `<#channelID>`.
Use that like this: `var message = "Make sure to check the rules at <#channelID>";`

Comment: Strange, the edited works for me. What method are you using to send the message?

Comment: I'm using a basic msg.reply

Comment: `message.guild.channels.find` is wrong, should be `message.guild.channels.cache.find`.

Comment: Can confirm `Edit` portion of the answer works.