# Have the Discord Bot link another Channel

Tags: javascript, json, bots, discord, discord.js

I have a Discord bot and I want it to direct someone to a different channel if they use the trigger word(s). I know I'm probably missing a line or two of code to do it.

```
bot.on("message", message => {
    if(message.content.toLowerCase().indexOf('lists') > -1) {
        message.channel.send(`Please visit #bt-updates for information on the current list information!`);
    }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a bot to mention a channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49353929/how-do-i-get-a-bot-to-mention-a-channel)

Comment: I had tried that and it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**let room1 = message.channel.guild.channels.find('id', 'ChannelID');**
message.channel.send(`Please visit ${room1} for information on the current list information!`);
}

Answer (score 4):

Based on your response to HolyDragon, it seems you're looking for how to give the "blue link" for the channel in your response?

If so, you need the channel id for #bt-updates, and to return it as

```
bot.on("message", message => {
  if(message.content.toLowerCase() === 'lists') {
    message.channel.send(`Please visit <#${id}> for information on the current list information!`);
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using `===` instead of `indexOf()`.

```
bot.on("message", message => {
    if(message.content.toLowerCase() === 'lists') {
        message.channel.send(`Please visit #bt-updates for information on the current list information!`);
    }
});
```

Official example for [Ping](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/examples/ping).

Comment: Does the same thing as my original code. Doesn't link the #bt-updates in the message