# How to check if a user is writing a message in a shared channel and tell him or her to write in a bot-specific channel

Tags: discord.js, channel, transmission

How to check if a user is writing a message in a shared channel and tell him to write in a bot-specific channel?

This is the code I tried:

```js
if (message.channel.id === "bot-playground"){
    // write code here
}else {
    message.channel.send("Write commands in #bot-playground.").then(msg => {
        timeout(3000, msg);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    if (message.channel.id === "bot-playground"){
```

This needs a channel ID, not a name. To get the ID of the channel, right-click it and select `copy ID` then use this. if you don't have the `copy ID` button you may need to [Enable developer mode](https://discordia.me/en/developer-mode)

Also, your mention may not work

```
message.channel.send("Write commands in #bot-playground.")
```

See

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49353929/how-do-i-get-a-bot-to-mention-a-channel) for more

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is caused by the first line `if (message.channel.id === "bot-playground")` you are trying to use the channel name as an ID.

You either need to look it up using the ID of the channel, which you can get by [enabling `Developer Mode`](https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/206346498-Where-can-I-find-my-User-Server-Message-ID-)

Or, you could just use the channel name to find it like so:

`message.guilds.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'bots-playground')`

Answer (score 0):

Replace client with whatever variable or constant used to assign the [Discord#Client](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client) object.

```js
client.on("typingStart", (channel, user) => {

     const bot_channel = channel.guild.channels.cache.find(chan => chan.name == "bot-playground");

     if (channel.id != bot_channel.id) {
          return message.channel.send(`Write commands in <#${bot_channel.id}>`);
     }

});
```